# How is possible to identify Tampering Data in Hidden Field in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Introduction**

It is required to identify the changes made by someone in hidden field through `tampering data` application.

**Snapshot**

[image: In the snapshot, <code>hidden field</code> tampering application is opened and all the fields are there including text fields as well as hidden fields. The price has been changed from 2999 to 29.]

**Question**

How to identify that the someone is changing the hidden field value our web page through this application? Is there any way to identify in `JavaScript` (through `AJAX` or `JQuery` code)? or is there any other way to identify?

Answer (score 1):

If your are loading the value into a hidden field, then I am assuming you know what the value is and should be.

**Option One:**
Store the value in a session before the hidden input gets displayed and then compare on form post.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['hiddenValue'] = $someValue;

<form action="http://somedomain.com/endpoint" method="post">
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $someValue;?>"/>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then on POST:

```
<?php
   if($_POST['hidden'] != $_SESSION['hiddenValue']) {
         // Hidden value has been changed.
   }
```

**Option Two:**
Read the value back from database or other data source and compare with post.

```
$someValue = // Load value from your data source

<form action="http://somedomain.com/endpoint" method="post">
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $someValue;?>"/>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then on POST:

```
<?php
   $someValue = // Load value from your data source

   if($_POST['hidden'] != $someValue) {
         // Hidden value has been changed.
   }
```

Comment: You cannot as you have no control over the 'tampering application'. The other option is on form submission is to do an AJAX request and compare the hidden field value with the data source value and they don't match then prevent form submission. In any case you should also be doing the check server side.

Comment: You will need to update your question with more details as it is vague. I am not sure what your 'tampering application' is. In any case you have to compare the hidden value with a known value. If it is done after form submission then how is it a hidden input?